# Merging a column under a specific criteria under sql sever 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I have this problem that I have been trying to fix for a few hours now, basically I have an SQL code that prints the tables in the database and their columns along with some other information which looks as follow:
[What I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRUc3.png)

The problem is that I wanna remove duplicates in the first column which shows the name of the table but I wanna leave the 'columns' attribute in different rows, basically I need the duplicates to become empty or to merge the first column of the rows that represent the same table. I Know this is broad explanation but this is what I want it to look like:[wanted result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUxCu.png)

this is the sql code I am using under sql server 2014:

```
SELECT CAST(t.NAME AS CHAR(12)) AS [Table]
,CAST(c.NAME AS CHAR(20)) AS [Column]
,CAST(d.NAME AS CHAR(9)) AS [Data type]
,CASE 
    WHEN d.NAME IN (
            'char'
            ,'varchar'
            )
        THEN STR(c.max_length, 6, 0)
    ELSE ''
    END AS [Length]
,CASE 
    WHEN d.NAME IN (
            'numeric'
            ,'decimal'
            )
        THEN STR(c.precision, 9, 0)
    ELSE ''
    END AS [Precision]
,CASE 
    WHEN d.NAME IN (
            'numeric'
            ,'decimal'
            )
        THEN STR(c.scale, 5, 0)
    ELSE ''
    END AS [Scale]
,CASE c.is_nullable
    WHEN 0
        THEN 'not null'
    ELSE ''
    END AS [Nullable]
FROM sys.columns AS c
JOIN sys.tables AS t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
JOIN sys.types AS d ON c.system_type_id = d.system_type_id
ORDER BY 1
    ,column_id;
```

The code should work for any database under sql server 2008 or more. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work;

```
WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY t.NAME ORDER BY c.NAME
            ) AS ID
        ,CAST(t.NAME AS CHAR(12)) AS [Table]
        ,CAST(c.NAME AS CHAR(20)) AS [Column]
        ,CAST(d.NAME AS CHAR(9)) AS [Data type]
        ,CASE 
            WHEN d.NAME IN (
                    'char'
                    ,'varchar'
                    )
                THEN STR(c.max_length, 6, 0)
            ELSE ''
            END AS [Length]
        ,CASE 
            WHEN d.NAME IN (
                    'numeric'
                    ,'decimal'
                    )
                THEN STR(c.precision, 9, 0)
            ELSE ''
            END AS [Precision]
        ,CASE 
            WHEN d.NAME IN (
                    'numeric'
                    ,'decimal'
                    )
                THEN STR(c.scale, 5, 0)
            ELSE ''
            END AS [Scale]
        ,CASE c.is_nullable
            WHEN 0
                THEN 'not null'
            ELSE ''
            END AS [Nullable]
    FROM sys.columns AS c
    JOIN sys.tables AS t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
    JOIN sys.types AS d ON c.system_type_id = d.system_type_id
    )
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN ct.ID = 1
            THEN ct.[Table]
        ELSE ''
        END AS 'Table'
    ,ct.[Column]
    ,ct.[Data type]
    ,ct.Length
    ,ct.Precision
    ,ct.Scale
    ,ct.Nullable
FROM CTE ct
```